# iOS 7 iAd Implementation

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, iad, ads

I have submitted three iOS apps and they have all been approved. I implemented iAd into them, and the test ads show when I test the apps. But now they have been on the  App Store for a few days, and I haven't seen any ads when I download the apps on devices that are not provisioned as test devices. I have already accepted the iAd contract, and the iAd page simply says "iAd Network is temporarily unavailable Sorry: We were unable to locate information relating to your account. Please try again later".

Comment: The add is displayed in the app based on the availability of ads.

Comment: @jailani Ok. What about the iAd module? Is it down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently had an app approved that went live on the App Store.  After the app is approved and live on the App Store the app has to be reviewed by iAd for use on the App Network to determine its appropriateness for receiving ads from iAd advertisers.  It took approximately two weeks after my app went live to be approved by the iAd group and had ads being pushed to the app

Comment: Ok. Will I be notified once the iAd reviewers have completed their review?

Comment: I received a message from Apple in the iAd Reports messages and you'll also see your app appear in the iAd Reports - My Apps section.  The new app will also show Live Ads in the list if receiving ads

Comment: Does it say iAd is temporarily unavailable because the apps are in iAd review?

Answer (score 0):

I did not receive a message stating the app was in review in iAd.  The app was missing from my list of iAd apps running ads until it was approved and running live ads

Comment: Where is the list of iAd apps?

Comment: the iAd workbench is for ad creation. I do not see a tab for my apps, only for creating iAd campaigns.

Comment: Here is the link that got me to the View Your iAd Reports, https://iad.apple.com/itcportal/#app_homepage

Comment: I go there, but I get the message "iAd network is temporarily unavailable. Sorry: We were unable to locate information relating to your account. Please try again later." I have seen that message for about a week. I have never been able to view my apps. I've always seen that message whenever I've tried to log on.

Comment: Did you complete your Contracts, Tax, and banking Info on iTunes Connect. You need to file one for the iAd Network as your first step

Comment: If the effective date has past, then yes.